# How to return a list with replaced string elements? Python

Tags: python, replace

I`ve got some problem with the following task: a user enters some cells like "XXXOO__O_". I print out it then like this (kind of a matrix/board):

```
---------
| X X X |
| O O _ |
| _ O _ |
---------
```

then the user enters two coordinates from 1 to 3, for example `2 3`. After that I do some checks and if cell is "_" I replace it with "X" and then print board with replaced element again.

```
print("Enter cells:")
cells = input()
print("---------")
print("|", cells[0], cells[1], cells[2], "|")
print("|", cells[3], cells[4], cells[5], "|")
print("|", cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], "|")
print("---------")

while True:
    coord = input("Enter the coordinates:").split()
    strng = "".join(coord)

    is_0_3 = 0
    if strng.isdigit() == True:
        for c in coord:
            if int(c) > 3 or int(c) <= 0:
                is_0_3 = 1
    if strng.isdigit() == True and len("".join(coord)) == 2:
        index = (((int(coord[0]) - 1) * 3) + (int(coord[1]) + 2)) - 3 #turning usser`s coordinates #into list index
        print("index", index)
        mtrx = []
        for y in range(len(cells)):
            mtrx.append(cells[y])
        is_occupied = 0
        for i, cell in enumerate(mtrx):
            if i == index:
                print("i==index", i)
                if mtrx[index] == "X" or mtrx[index] == "O":
                    is_occupied = 1


    if strng.isdigit() == False:
        print("You should enter numbers!")
    elif len("".join(coord)) != 2:
        print("You should enter 2 numbers!")
    elif is_0_3 == 1:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
    elif is_occupied == 1:
        print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")

    else:
        print("ma[i] before", mtrx[index])
        mtrx[i] = mtrx[index].replace("_", "X")
        print(mtrx[i])
        print("i", i)
        new_mtrx = []
        print("---------")
        for i in range(0, 8, 3):
            row = [mtrx[i], mtrx[i + 1], mtrx[i + 2]]
            new_mtrx.append(row)
            print(f"| {mtrx[i]} {mtrx[i + 1]} {mtrx[i + 2]} |")
        print("---------")
        break
```

The problem is that `i` in the last `else` is always 8 and the element with coordinates `3 3` is always replaced no matter what coordinates the user entered. I don't understand why... Could you explain how can I fix it, please? For user's input `2 3` index=5 and the cell is '_', but in the last `for` the element with coordinates `3 3` is replaced, not the element with `2 3`. I need to replace the element with coordinates user entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your last last else statement, you need to enumerate the matrix again.  This worked for me.

```
else:
        for i, cell in enumerate(mtrx):
            index == i
        print("ma[i] before", mtrx[i])
        mtrx[index] = mtrx[index].replace("_", "X")
        print(mtrx[i])
        print("i", i)
        new_mtrx = []
        print("---------")
        for i in range(0, 8, 3):
            row = [mtrx[i], mtrx[i + 1], mtrx[i + 2]]
            new_mtrx.append(row)
            print(f"| {mtrx[i]} {mtrx[i + 1]} {mtrx[i + 2]} |")
        print("---------")
        break
```

Comment: thank you so much! You are a lifesaver! i'm new to Python, so I would never conjectured it

Answer (score 1):

I would keep things simple and use basic string manipulations here:

```py
def print_board(inp):
    print("---------")
    lines = re.findall(r'.{3}', inp)
    lines_out = ["| " + x[0] + " " + x[1] + " " + x[2] + " |" for x in lines]
    for line_out in lines_out:
        print(line_out)
    print("---------")

inp = "XXXOO__O_"
print_board(inp)
```

This prints:

```
---------
| X X X |
| O O _ |
| _ O _ |
---------
```